# How can I avoid resource leak when using a semaphore?

Tags: linux, posix, semaphore, glibc

Linux `sem_destroy()` documentation says:

> An  unnamed  semaphore should be destroyed with `sem_destroy()` before the memory in which it is
>   located is deallocated.  Failure to do this can result in resource leaks on  some  implementations.

But the best I can do is register `sem_destroy()` to `atexit()`, which won't be called on aborts or `SIGKILL`. I have a process responsible for creating and destroying a semaphore on shared memory (a mmaped file), how can I avoid a resource leak on abnormal termination conditions?

On Linux, if the mmaped file is deleted before `sem_destroy()` is called, is any kind of resource leaked? What resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glibc implementation of `sem_destroy` does nothing, and this will not change.  If you use glibc, you do not have to do anything for freeing up resources.  Furthermore, the kernel would free such resources on process termination anyway.

The glibc implementation of semaphores is based on [futexes](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/futex.pdf), which is why it does not need any additional resources besides the memory used to store the semaphore.

Comment: Kernel couldn't free the resources if the semaphore is shared between processes. A new process using trying to use the semaphore could be spawned any time.

Comment: The resources for storing that are associated with the file, not the process. Waiting futexes need some storage, but only while waiting, so that doesn't matter here, either. In fact, I find it difficult to imagine a conforming implementation of process-shared semaphores where `sem_destroy` actually frees any resources.